# SSO between ASP.Net and JSP

Tags: asp.net, jsp, architecture, single-sign-on, membership

I built an **ASP.Net MVC 4** application which uses forms authentication by means of a custom membership provider inheriting from the Simple Membership.

Everything is working fine, but now I have a new requirement: **I need to integrate a JSP application with mine**.

This means that it has to authenticate against the same user database of my application and that they should somehow share the session in order to achieve a kind of Single Sign-On among the two applications (`if an user is already authenticated in the ASP.Net application`, **he should be able to access the JSP application without logging in again,** and vice-versa).

What architecture do you suggest me to use?

I would like to change as little as possible the ASP.Net application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to auhtenticate accross **different domains**:

You can implement your own security token service (like facebook, google does)  Here is some ready to use implementation: http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/

If the sites are running on the **same domain (subdomain)**, then you can try to share an authentication cookie  within these domains.

An explaining article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Comment: The sites are in the same domain, so probably the authentication cookie could be viable... May you just elaborate a little more this option or point me to some reference about it?

Comment: @user1859941 I edited my answer and added a reference to one article which may drive you to the right direction.