# ASP.NET authentication provider shared among multiple sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I want to set-up a central Authentication Provider for multiple ASP.NET sites on multiple machines.

I don't need to share login sessions, but if it is not to much trouble then it would be a nice feature.

Primary goal is to have a global roles and login details. If they have to login again its not to bad.

How would I go about doing this? Or should I ask what would be the best way to go about doing it?

Obviously copying the database to each site is not a valid option.

I plan on using the built in Authentication Services in asp.net to Authenticate users who try and access the different sites.

A better idea which I had was to all share a common database. What is your opinion on this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to share only user credentials or also user authentication session (single sign on)?

Comment: I only really need to share creditals

Comment: Then common database is sufficient solution but i would prefer single sign on. Look at one of my previous answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254796/sso-between-asp-net-and-jsp/21281154#21281154.

Comment: WHen reading up on this I see that each site uses it own encryption. Will simply pointing the sites to the same authentication database just work?